# Check File extension in php when file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, file-extension

I have check extension of uploaded file in php if `jpg|png|gif` than upload otherwise not allow to upload

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

but what happen when i change `.php` or `.mp3` file to `jpg|png|gif` and upload

so how i can stop this type of file upload in php

Comment: gif, png and jpgs are allowed so they would be uploaded. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: `exif_imagetype` will do your rescue

Answer (score 2):

With this you can get the mimetype and can check against your "whitelist":

```
 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```